# Isotope masonry to build a metro style page

Tags: html, sorting, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I have a problem in using isotope to build a metro style page.

Sample code in https://codepen.io/erds/pen/QqRLRg

```
<div class="container container-grid">

        <div class="grid-item height-4 width-6">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item height-2 width-6">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item height-2 width-6">
            <p>3</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item height-3 width-4">
            <p>4</p>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item  height-1 width-4">
            <p>5</p>
        </div>

</div>
```

Why are not 4 and 5 next to 2 and 3?

Comment: Its because you are using a masonry layout, which will order based on the best fit rather than sequentially